# MATLAB Coder: Truncating/concatenating cell arrays

Tags: matlab, code-generation

I'm trying to generate C-Code from a MATLAB function. I have to work with cell arrays (I cannot change this) and there are occurring two problems:

1: I want to truncate a cell array, i.e.

```
arr = cell(1,n); 
% ...
arr = arr(1:m);   % with m<n
```

MATLAB Coder forbids the `(...)` indexing, so I tried the following

```
tmp = arr;
arr = cell(1,m);
for i = 1:m
    arr{i} = tmp{i};
end
```

But this will throw the error, that 'Matlab is unable to determine that every element of tmp{:} is assigned before this line'. The same happens if I assign every element of `arr` to `tmp` in a loop.

2. The same problem occurs when I try to concatenate two cell arrays.

Do you know how to fix this, so that MATLAB Coder won't throw any errors.

Comment: Interesting that it won't acknowledge `tmp = arr;` as a copy... maybe the corer takes a pointer sometimes and its getting confused here. Can you initialize temp before the copy with `tmp=cell(1,n);`? Maybe even making a loop for `tmp = arr;`, instead of a single line

Comment: I tried to copy `arr` to `tmp` by a loop, but that gave the same error message.

Comment: Including the initialization I suggested?

Comment: yes, exactly...

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what version of MATLAB Coder you're using you can get this error.
In order to avoid the complete assignment detection problem you can type:

```
arr = coder.nullcopy(cell(1,m));
```

But you need to promise you're writing to every cell element after that assignment (which you are doing, because

```
for i = 1:m
    arr{i} = tmp{i};
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with embedded curly braces.

```
arr_trunc = {arr{1:m}}
```

I hope this helps. I tested this with Coder and didn't get an error.